# django updating google chart using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, google-visualization

This is the first time I am using AJAX so I was trying to make net usage monitor. I want to draw a dynamically changing graph. I am using google charts along with Django.

Here is what i have in my JavaScript

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(repeat);
function repeat(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/net/refresh/",
      dataType:"json",
      type:"GET",
      success: function(data) {
        var djangoData = {{data|safe}}
        drawChart(djangoData)
        }
      });

setTimeout(repeat,3000);
}

function get_gchart_data(data) 
{
  var g_data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
  return g_data;
}
function drawChart(djangoData) {
    var g_data = get_gchart_data(djangoData);
    console.log('hello')
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new 

google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(g_data, {width: 1000, height: 240, title: "Net usage"});
    }
```

The view from where i retrieve the data array required is as follows

```
  def new(request):
    a = [-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5]
    alpha = []
    c = ['Time','Usage']
    alpha.append(c)
    i=0
    for i in range(0,7):
        c=[a[i],randint(0,50)]
        alpha.append(c)
    data = {'data':alpha}
    if request.is_ajax():
        print(alpha)
        try:
            print('hello')
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type='application/json')
        except:
            return render(request,'netusage/working.html',data)
        # return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

On running this console.log() in chartDraw does not get printed which simply means success is not being called. Anyone can suggest where i am going wrong. Something intuitive would be great as I have no good knowledge of AJAX.

Comment: maybe check for errors in the `fail:` callback...? --> `fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}`